# to def or not to def @groovy

Tags: groovy, function

There is a groovy script that has a function defined and used in multiple threads.
I found that time to time it mixes some variable values with other threads.
The problem appears when developer forgot to declare variable like this:

```
def f ( x ) {
  y = "" + x
  println y
}
```

The problem disappears when developer declares variable

```
def f ( x ) {
  def y = "" + x
  println y
}
```

In classes there is no way to use undefined variables.

The reason is that in the scripts the undefined variable acts as an instance variable of the script-class. Actually this is a binding for external variables that could be passed into the script.

Here is a part of script that demonstrates the problem of using undefined variables in several threads.

```
void f(String x){
    y=""+x;  //if you put def at this line it'll work fine
    Thread.sleep(333);
    //usually developers expected that `y` is a local variable, 
    //but without declaration it belongs to script-class
    if( !y.equals(x) ) println("failure: x=$x y=$y");
}

//thead 1 start
Thread.start{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        f( i.toString() )
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}

//thead 2 start
Thread.start{
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        f( i.toString() )
        Thread.sleep(150);
    }
}

//main thread sleep.
Thread.sleep(2000);
println("done");
```

this code will print out failures when x not equals y (literally)

Comment: Looks like you have already discovered what is the problem. Then why the question of whether to define or not define?

Answer (score 2):

Write a compiler configuration using a `scriptBaseClass` to disallow undeclared variables and the usage of the script's own binding.

This is the base script (my `DefBase.groovy` file):

```
abstract class NoUndefShallPass extends Script {
  void setProperty(String name, val) { 
    // seems like groovy itself set 'args' in the binding, probably from CL
    assert name == 'args', 
        "Error in '$name'; variables should be declared using 'def'" 
  }
}

def configuration = new org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.setScriptBaseClass(NoUndefShallPass.class.name)

def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), configuration)


shell.evaluate new File('/tmp/Defing.groovy')
```

And the script. It will thrown an `AssertionError` if the `setProperty` tries to use the binding:

```
void f(String x){
    y=""+x;  //if you put def at this line it'll work fine
    Thread.sleep(333);
    if( !y.equals(x) ) println("failure: x=$x y=$y");
}

def t1 = Thread.start{
    20.times { i ->
        f( i.toString() )
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}

def t2 = Thread.start{
    20.times { i ->
        f( i.toString() )
        Thread.sleep(150);
    }
}

Thread.sleep(2000);
t1.join()
t2.join()
println("done");
```

Answer (score 0):

it's poorly described here as "the binding"

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22